# problema con where en laravel

Tags: laravel

Este es el error que me da en una consulta, sin embargo en otra consulta sin problema me funciona.

> SQLSTATE [42S22]: Columna no encontrada: 1054 Columna desconocida 'ventas'. en 'where cláusula' (SQL: seleccione ``` ventas``id ```,``` ventas``tipo_comprobante ```, ``` ventas``serie_comprobante ```,``` ventas``num_comprobante ```, ``` ventas``fecha_hora ```,``` ventas``impuesto ```, ``` ventas``total ```,``` ventas``estado ```, ``` personas``nombre ```,``` users``usuario ``` de `ventas` inner join`personas` en `ventas`.`idcliente` =``` personas``id ``` unirse a `users` en``` ventas``idusuario ``` = ``` users``id ``` donde```` ventas``` como %% ordenar por ````ventas`.`fecha_hora` desc)

Mi consulta es public function

```
listarPdfventa(Request $request){
      $buscar = $request->buscar;
    $criterio = $request->criterio;

     $ventas = Venta::join('personas','ventas.idcliente','=','personas.id')
        ->join('users','ventas.idusuario','=','users.id')
        ->select('ventas.id','ventas.tipo_comprobante','ventas.serie_comprobante',
        'ventas.num_comprobante','ventas.fecha_hora','ventas.impuesto','ventas.total',
        'ventas.estado','personas.nombre','users.usuario') 
        ->where('ventas.'.$criterio, 'like', '%'. $buscar . '%')
       ->orderBy('ventas.fecha_hora', 'desc')->get();
```

Tengo una vista que me trae todos los registros de la bd si no pongo nada en el buscador y si pongo un criterio en el buscador me trae ese con este where, yo quiero reutilizar esta consulta en otra función para que me lleve a PDF la vista que tengo en pantalla pero no me funciona.

Comment: ¿Por qué no utilizas las relaciones de Eloquent para la consulta?

Comment: es que estoy comensando recien, viste que quiero crear un reporte pdf por fecha pero yo tengo una vista que tiene un buscador y pensaba reutilizar dicha funcion en una nueva para que cuando le doy pdf no me traida el total de la consulta si no lo que yo tenga en mi vista, es solo una idea no se como seria mejor, gracias

Comment: ¿Qué viene conteniendo la variable $criterio?